# Figuring out the proper numpy.reshape for -1 option

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a (hopefully) quick Numpy question, and I hope you can help me.
I want to use numpy.reshape to convert (5000, 32, 32, 3) into (5000, 3072), and the only clue I got for the assignment is this:

```
# Reshape each image data into a 1-dim array
print (X_train.shape, X_test.shape) # Should be: (5000, 32, 32, 3) (500, 32, 32, 3)
#####################################################################
# TODO (2):                                                         #
# Reshape the image data to one dimension.                          #
#                                                                   #
# Hint: Look at the numpy reshape function and have a look at -1    # 
#       option                                                      #
#####################################################################
X_train = 
X_test = 
#####################################################################
#                       END OF YOUR CODE                            #
#####################################################################
print (X_train.shape, X_test.shape) # Should be: (5000, 3072) (500, 3072)
```

I've been spending the last day scouring Google for examples, but apparently this is too trivial to warrant an ask. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (5000, -1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (500, -1))
```

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((5000,32,32,3))
b = np.reshape(a, (5000, -1))

print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)

# Output
# (5000, 32, 32, 3)
# (5000, 3072)
```

*numpy.reshape* will try to fit the source array *a* into an array with first dimension of length 5000. The -1 tells reshape to adjust the length of the second dimension depending on the total length of the source array *a*.

Comment: And here I was, looking for a clever dynamic solution that I somehow missed, when the solution was literally that obvious. Thx man.